# Calculating the accumulate moving average of a group of data in Table

Tags: numerics, output-formatting, formatting

basically I have a group of data in dimension (21*51), I managed to generate the name of the file and Imported into a Table

```
 name = Table[StringTemplate["/Users/Projekt/output/log/b7_t`t`_a`a`.dat", InsertionFunction -> (ToString@NumberForm[#, {2, 2}] &)]@<|"t" -> 0.01 k, "a" -> 0.01 l|>, {k, 1, 21}, {l, 0, 50}];
 data = Table[Import[name[[i, j]]], {i, 1, 21}, {j, 1, 51}]
```

The dimension of both name and data are

```
 In[28]= Dimensions[data]
Out[29]= {21, 51}
```

Now, each file has a list of numbers, and I intend to do the calculation of accumulative moving average of each file, and put them under one table for later use, I know for each single file the method would simply be for example

```
cma = Accumulate[data1]/Range[1, Length[data1]]
```

but when I change data into `data[[i,j]]` and define `{i,1,21},{j,1,51}`, it will simply break down, much appreciate if anyone can give me some help!

Comment: There's [`MovingAverage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingAverage.html).

Comment: I just calculate the average with respect to the current number of data, not by a fixed window

Comment: `cma = Table[
  Accumulate[data[[i]]]/Range[1, Length[data[[i]]]], {i, 1, 
   Length@data}]`

Comment: Hi@corey979, I'm not sure if the code works or not, because it consumes too much memory, my 16Gb ram is simply not enough, is there a computationally cheaper way to do this?

Comment: This code, for `data = RandomReal[1, {21, 51}]` having `Dimensions@data == {21, 51}`, runs in `0.002418 sec` (`AbsoluteTiming`). I cannot know what are you doing there; maybe you have some old definitions, corrupted data, or your data has some other format than follows from your question.

Comment: Hi @corey979, I found out the reason why I'm getting massive memory consumption, It turns out the the dimension of the data I generated is `{21, 51, 255, 1}`, 255 comes from 255 data points in each file, in this case, I changed 

       `cma = Table[
  Accumulate[data[[i, j]]]/Range[data[[i, j]]], {i, 1, 21}, {j, 
   1, 50}]`

 Output doesn't seem to be right at all, any suggestion what can be done to fix this?

Comment: just to correct a typo in the above comment
     `cma = Table[ Accumulate[data[[i, j]]]/Range[1, Length[data[[i, j]]]], {i, 1, 21}, {j, 1, 50}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the method mentioned in the question, the actual Dimension for data would be `{21,51,Length[data],1}`.
So here's the solution

```
Table[Accumulate[data[[i, j]]]/Range[1, Length[data[[i, j]]]], {i, 1, 21}, {j, 1, 50}]
```

Thanks corey979